# Cannot invoke '...' with an argument list of type '...'

Tags: ios, swift

This line:

```
appDelegate.navigationController.pushViewControllerOnTopOfEverything(controller)
```

causes this error:

```
Cannot invoke 'pushViewControllerOnTopOfEverything' with an argument list of type '(VUPickerController!)'
```

Here's the full function:

```
    func onSortTapped() {

    if self.pickerModel == nil {
        self.pickerModel = VUPickerModel.newOrExistingPickerModelForKey(VUPickerModelKeyType.ShowsSort)
    }

    var controller = VUPickerController(model: self.pickerModel) { (selectionChanged) in

        if selectionChanged {
            self.pickerModel?.archiveWithModelKeyType(VUPickerModelKeyType.ShowsSort)

            let userSelections = self.pickerModel!.selectedRows()
            let sectionItem = userSelections![0] as! VUPickerSectionItem
            self.leftGenreBar?.genreName = sectionItem.title
        }
    }

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
    appDelegate.navigationController.pushViewControllerOnTopOfEverything(controller)

}
```

`navigationController` is a custom `UIViewController` written in Obj-C, and `pushViewControllerOnTopOfEverything` is defined as:

```
- (void)pushViewControllerOnTopOfEverything:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Also, `VUPickerController` is subclassed from `UIViewController`.

---

`onSortTapped()` was originally written in Obj-C and I'm trying to do a simple translation, but I'm missing something.

---

I did try casting to a `UIViewController`:

```
appDelegate.navigationController.pushViewControllerOnTopOfEverything(controller as! UIViewController)
```

but got a similar error:

```
Cannot invoke 'pushViewControllerOnTopOfEverything' with an argument list of type '(UIViewController)'
```

---

EDIT

When I try to:

```
po appDelegate.navigationController
```

in the debug console I get:

```
error: <EXPR>:1:13: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

If I just po:

```
po appDelegate
```

I get:

```
Printing description of appDelegate:
Optional(<AppDelegate: 0x7f81a2d1cc40>)
```

And `navigationController` is a property of appDelegate, declared in the original Obj-C `appDelegate.h` file.

Comment: Have you try to use pushViewControllerOnTopOfEverything with an plain UIViewControler?

Comment: @Icaro Just tried that and same error.

Comment: there isn't any other pushViewControllerOnTopOfEverything somewhere in the code where swift can be getting confuse?