# "type of expression is ambiguous without more context" - Referencing appDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I have my `appDelegate` originally written in Obj-C. I'm trying to access it in a new Swift class, but am get a strange error that I think is misleading, and I'm trying to get to the root.

In my Swift file, I've set a breakpoint after:

```
var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
```

If I just po:

```
po appDelegate
```

I get:

```
Printing description of appDelegate:
Optional(<AppDelegate: 0x7f81a2d1cc40>)
```

Everything is fine.

However, when I try to:

```
po appDelegate.navigationController
```

in the debug console I get:

```
error: <EXPR>:1:13: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

And navigationController is a property of appDelegate, declared in the original Obj-C appDelegate.h file.

---

Here's my original SO question: [Cannot invoke '...' with an argument list of type '...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878508/cannot-invoke-with-an-argument-list-of-type)

---

EDIT

Based on @Martin's comment, I changed my code to:

```
  var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!
  appDelegate.navigationController.popViewControllerIsAnimated(true)
```

Which now brings up an error:

```
'UIApplicationDelegate' does not have a member named 'navigationController'
```

However, here's my Obj-C AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) VUNavigationController *navigationController;

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: `appDelegate` is apparently an *optional*. Does it work if you define `var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!` instead?

Comment: @MartinR That did something - see my edit. A new error - it's like I'm accessing a different AppDelegate object now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `delegate` method of `UIApplication` is declared as

```
unowned(unsafe) var delegate: UIApplicationDelegate?
```

You have to cast the return value to the concrete type of your application delegate:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```